# Need to sort array object based on other string array and remove unmatch object

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Need to sort array object based on other string array and remove unmatch object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class Test {
    String name;
    int no;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", no=" + no +
                '}';
    }

    public static Test createStudent(String name, int no) {
        Test student = new Test();
        student.setName(name);
        student.setNo(no);
        return student;
    }


    public static void sortStudentInArrayList(List<String> scppriority) {
        List<Test> students = new ArrayList<>();
        Test student1 = createStudent("SCP1", 3);
        students.add(student1);
        Test student2 = createStudent("SCP2", 1);
        students.add(student2);
        Test student3 =  createStudent("SCP3", 5);
        students.add(student3);
        Test student4 = createStudent("SCP4", 2);
        students.add(student4);
        
       
        //students.retainAll(scppriority);
        System.out.println("Original students list: " + students);
        
       
        Collections.sort(students, Comparator.comparing(s -> scppriority.indexOf(s.getName())));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<String> string2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        string2.add("SCP2");
        string2.add("SCP3");

               

        sortStudentInArrayList(string2);
}
}
```

<** output Original students list: [Student{name='SCP1', no=3}, Student{name='SCP4', no=2}, Student{name='SCP2', no=1}, Student{name='SCP3', no=5}]
need to remove unmatch from student list, Thanks in Advance**>

Comment: Can you add the expected set of students in output??

Comment: Thanks @SabareeshMuralidharan.
the expected output should be 

Student{Student{name='SCP2', no=1}, Student{name='SCP3', no=5}]

based on string2 defined order

Comment: And you don't want to use retainAll?

Comment: yes retainAll, I tried but got not able to success as I have object array and string array .

any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
List<Test> result = students.stream()
        .filter(student -> scppriority.contains(student.getName()))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> scppriority.indexOf(s.getName())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Original students list: " + result);
```

Output:

```
Original students list: [Student{name='SCP2', no=1}, Student{name='SCP3', no=5}]
```